# p.OutputDataRecived and p.ErrorDataRecived both has null value when i am trying to create azure function for converting the html content into pdf

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, wkhtmltopdf

I Created one HTTP Azure function for converting the HTML Content to PDF by using wkhtmltopdf. My function is returning pdf file but when i am trying to open the PDF file i am getting an error "PDF file was unable to load". When i backtracked my issue i found that p.OutputDataRecived and p.ErorDataRecived both has empty value.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string localPath = req.RequestUri.LocalPath;
string functionName = localPath.Substring(localPath.LastIndexOf('/')+1);

var json = File.ReadAllText(string.Format(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\{0}\FunctionConfig.json",functionName));

var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

var functionArguments = config.input.arguments;
var localOutputFolder = Path.Combine(@"d:\home\data", config.output.folder.Value, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetTempFileName()));
Directory.CreateDirectory(localOutputFolder);
var workingDirectory = Path.Combine(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot", functionName + "\\bin");
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);//fun fact - the default working directory is d:\windows\system32

var command = config.input.command.Value;

var argList = new List<ExeArg>(); 


foreach (var arg in functionArguments)
{
    var exeArg = new ExeArg();
    exeArg.Name = arg.Name;
    var value = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)arg.Value;
    var property = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)value.First;
    exeArg.Type = property.Name;
    exeArg.Value = property.Value.ToString(); 

    var valueFromQueryString = await getValueFromQuery(req, exeArg.Name);

    log.Info("valueFromQueryString name=" + exeArg.Name);
    log.Info("valueFromQueryString val=" + valueFromQueryString);
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueFromQueryString))
    {
        exeArg.Value = valueFromQueryString;
        log.Info(exeArg.Name + " " + valueFromQueryString);
    }

    if(exeArg.Type.ToLower() == "localfile" || exeArg.Type.ToLower() == "localfolder")
    {
        exeArg.Value = Path.Combine(localOutputFolder, exeArg.Value);
        exeArg.Type = "string";
    }
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(exeArg.Value))
    {
        //throw exception here
    }
    argList.Add(exeArg);
}

//call the exe
Dictionary<string, string> paramList = ProcessParameters(argList, localOutputFolder);
foreach (string parameter in paramList.Keys)
{
    command = command.Replace(parameter, paramList[parameter]);
}
string commandName = command.Split(' ')[0];
string arguments = command.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2)[1];
log.Info(commandName + " "+arguments);
log.Info("the command is " + command);
log.Info("the working dir is " + workingDirectory);

string output = MainOutputProcess(commandName,arguments,log);
log.Info(output);
File.WriteAllText(localOutputFolder+"\\out.txt",output);

//handle return file
log.Info("handling return file localOutputFolder=" + localOutputFolder);
string outputFile = config.output.binaryFile.returnFile.Value;
string outputFileName = config.output.binaryFile.returnFileName.Value;
log.Info(outputFile + " " + outputFileName);
var path = Directory.GetFiles(localOutputFolder, outputFile)[0];

log.Info("returning this file " + path);
var result = new FileHttpResponseMessage(localOutputFolder);
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = outputFileName
};

return result; 
}
private static string MainOutputProcess(string command, string 
arguments,TraceWriter log)
{

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = command; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
p.Start();
var sync = new object();
var buf = new StringBuilder();
p.OutputDataReceived +=
    (sender, args) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        lock (sync)
        {
            buf.AppendLine(args.Data);
            log.Info("O: "+args.Data);
        }
    };
p.BeginOutputReadLine();

p.ErrorDataReceived +=
    (sender, args) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        lock (sync)
        {
            buf.AppendLine(args.Data);
            log.Info("E: "+args.Data);
        }
    };
p.BeginErrorReadLine();

if (!p.WaitForExit(10000))
    throw new ApplicationException();

lock (sync)
{
    var res = buf.ToString();
    return res;
}

}
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf should be supported in a Consumption or App Service plan? It should work only in App Service Plan Basic or higher. Kindly see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

Comment: Yeah, i am using only app service plan only

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your Kudu(SCM) console (see https://david-obrien.net/2016/07/azure-functions-kudu/), are you able to run the wkhtmltopdf command line tool successfully?

If yes, then there might actually be a problem with running the process using the Process() object inside your Function code. I belatedly saw that your code is trying redirect standard in/out, which is generally forbidden for security reasons.

Another option is to try actually loading the wkhtmltopdf library through the DinkToPdf wrapper as documented in this blog:

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/14/pdf-generation-in-azure-functions-v2.aspx